# Using the IfWinActive keyword in AutoHotKey

Tags: windows, autohotkey, latex

This question about the use of AutoHotKey is specific to a Windows LaTeX editor called [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/).

So, I was trying to write my first AutoHotKey (AHK) script, and wanted the shortcuts to be available only when the TeXniceCenter window was active. AHK provides the `IfWinActive` keyword to deal with these scenarios, however, I ran into some difficulties in using this keyword.

Here is a draft file I wrote:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
SetTitleMatchMode, Slow

#IfWinActive, .* TeXnicCenter *.
!t::
Send \texttt{{}{}}
return
```

The `#IfWinActive, .* TeXnicCenter *.` line, so that the pattern "TeXnicCenter" is found somewhere in the window name does not work.

There were some other options that I discarded

- I use TeXnicCenter mainly with projects, so that the window name shows up as "*projectname* - TeXnicCenter", so it is not feasible to use this as the argument to `IfWinActive`. Note that the window name is TeXnicCenter if working on standalone documents.
- Another option provided by AHK is that you use something called the `ahk_class` of the process, which is typically intuitive (and can be had from the handy bundled AHK tool, called Window Spy) -- for example, in the case of Chrome, it is `Chrome_WidgetWin_1`.

However, for TeXnicCenter, it shows the bizarre signature -- for example, for one of my projects, it is `Afx:000000013F370000:8:0000000000010005:0000000000000000:0000000012B80087`, and not only that, it is not constant *across TeXnicCenter windows*, as it usually is for other processes.

I am at a loss -- does anyone have experience setting up AHK with TeXnicCenter, and using the `IfWinActive` keyword? I have a feeling that this might be better directed at the developers of TeXnicCenter, but here's hoping.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You used `SetTitleMatchMode` to set the title-matching mode to `2` which means *A window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match.* So, it is trying to find `.* TeXnicCenter *.` in the title-bar. You should remove the `.*` and `*.` (unless the title bar actually contains those—which as far as I know, [it does not](http://images.google.com/images?q=TeXnicCenter)). You can set the title-matching mode to `RegEx` if you would rather use the regex syntax, (and even then, the `*.` is incorrect, it should be `.*`).

As for the class, I had the same issue with GraphEdit which for the main window has a window class like `Afx:1000000:b:10011:6:1070780` with the same pattern, but different numbers for each instance. I solved it by using regex mode (`SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx`) and a pattern like `^Afx:.+:.:.+:.:.+$`—you can specify the exact number of digits between the colons, but it’s unlikely you’ll *need* to.

(I eventually ended up simplifying the whole process by using [groups](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupAdd.htm).)

So, in your case, you would use one of the following:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
SetTitleMatchMode, Slow

#IfWinActive, TeXnicCenter
!t::
Send \texttt{{}{}}
return



SetTitleMatchMode, regex
SetTitleMatchMode, Slow

#IfWinActive, .* TeXnicCenter *.
!t::
Send \texttt{{}{}}
return
```

Here is my recommendation:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, regex
SetTitleMatchMode, Slow
GroupAdd, TXC, ^.*TeXnicCenter.*$ ahk_class ^Afx:.+:.:.+:.+:.*$

#IfWinExist, ahk_group TXC
  !t::
    Send \texttt{{}{}}
  return
#IfWinExist
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that your suggestions will work, and I will try them out and get back. But I just wanted to point out that I am using TeXnicCenter 2 (alpha), so in my case the window title does contain "TeXnicCenter". I can't see the image you have linked to, it shows up as a 503 error.

Comment: Yep, works like a charm. Thanks. I did change the `IfWinExist` to `IfWinActive` since that is what I needed.

Comment: *> in my case the window title does contain "TeXnicCenter"*   Yes, it will contain `TeXnicCenter` in the title-bar, but not `.*` or `.*`.     *> I can't see the image you have linked to, it shows up as a 503 error.*   I didn’t link to an image, I linked to Google Images. I guess GI must be blocked by your network.     *>  I did change the IfWinExist to IfWinActive since that is what I needed.*   Sure; but they are a little different, so as long you know the difference, you should be fine. ☺